# java.net.ConnectException: Failed to connect to /127.0.0.1:9080 realm Object server

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, realm

I just installed realm object server after seeing the documentation in the website.I created a login page (android) and i used syncronised user settings as per the  website. but my asynctask on create shows the above error. 
Here is my code :

```
public class RealAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

Realm realm;
String url = "http://127.0.0.1:9080";
long schemaVersion = 001;

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
    try {
        SyncCredentials syncCredentials = SyncCredentials.usernamePassword("realm-admin", "", true);
        SyncUser user = SyncUser.login(syncCredentials, serverUrl());
        SyncConfiguration config = new SyncConfiguration.Builder(user, realmUrl())
                .schemaVersion(schemaVersion)
                .build();
        realm.setDefaultConfiguration(config);
    }
    catch (Exception e){
        e.getCause();
    }
    return null;
}

private String realmUrl() {
    return url;
}

private String serverUrl() {
    return url;
}
}
```

I am deploying my application in my mobile and while debugging i got the above error message. 
Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 can be used if server and client are on the same device. You are using mobile phone. Wifi or mobile connection? Tell your setup please.

Comment: No Not on the same device. I am not using the emulator too.Please tell me how i can handle this?

Comment: Well answer my questions i would say.

Comment: use the servers ip adress insted of 127.0.0.1

Comment: mob connection, wifi it didnt work in either

Comment: You should tell your setup first. Your Android app is running on your mobile phone. Tell us where your server is running. I keep asking for the very elementary.

Comment: my server is running in my localhost  of my machine using  wifi(not my mob's connection)

Comment: So on a pc in the same network as the phone.  Well then the client should use the lan ip of your pc. Tell us how you determined that ip.

Comment: `running in my localhost of my machine `. You cannot talk in that way. Every device, every phone, every pc is its own localhost.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Connect the server and mobile on the same network** or host the server in web server.

Use server system's `IP Address` instead of `127.0.0.1`.

Use IP `10.0.2.2` if you are using an `Emulator`.

**Every system itself is a localhost so when you call 127.0.0.1 the system calls itself.**